# Percentage of IPad Downloads in ITunesconnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have some games in the Appstore. They are universal apps. I would like to know what percentage of the downloads come form ipad. I can not find that information in itunesconnect.

How can i get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to get such information is to include statistics like [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com).

Comment: Hi, the link is not formatted properly (the "." sign should be after "[1]"). Edit is too short so I can't do it.